# How to write a SQL query to pull a value from a nested json object identified by a variable field name

Tags: sql, sqlite, json-extract, sqlite-json1, kismet-wireless

**Problem:** how to write a `sqlite` statement to select a value from a nested `json` object when the needed name is dynamic / variable. It is also important that this can be done from a single `sql` statement. Eventually, this will be executed from within a `bash` script.

In the object sample below, I need to list all the `dot11.advertisedssid.ssid` in the `sql` database. An acceptable solution is to list all values of `dot11.advertisedssid.ssid` that exist in the `json` object, but I would like to understand how to query a dynamic `json` name (so I can get the other nested values).
In general I am using `json_extract` in my `sql` statement I just can’t figure out how to get to the ssid value (in this example)!

How do I know `733545801` is the field name and how can I then use it in the `json_extract` statement? And do that for all such nested objects.

**Examples:**

In general this is how I am querying other json values.

`select json_extract(devices.device,'$."dot11.device"."dot11.device.typeset"') from devices;`

An object sample from the database:

```
 "dot11.device": {
    "dot11.device.typeset": 257,
    "dot11.device.client_map": {

    },
    "dot11.device.num_client_aps": 0,
    "dot11.device.advertised_ssid_map": {
      "733545801": {
        "dot11.advertisedssid.ssid": "SampleFES-WiFi",
        "dot11.advertisedssid.ssidlen": 15,
        "dot11.advertisedssid.beacon": 1,
        "dot11.advertisedssid.probe_response": 1,
        "dot11.advertisedssid.channel": "6",
        "dot11.advertisedssid.ht_mode": "HT20",
        "dot11.advertisedssid.ht_center_1": 0,
        "dot11.advertisedssid.ht_center_2": 0,
        "dot11.advertisedssid.first_time": 1559567379,
        "dot11.advertisedssid.last_time": 1559567379,
        "dot11.advertisedssid.beacon_info": "",
        "dot11.advertisedssid.cloaked": 0,
        "dot11.advertisedssid.crypt_set": 268436162,
        "dot11.advertisedssid.maxrate": 65.000000,
        "dot11.advertisedssid.beaconrate": 10,
        "dot11.advertisedssid.beacons_sec": 2,
        "dot11.advertisedssid.ietag_checksum": 1220416683,
        "dot11.advertisedssid.wpa_mfp_required": 0,
        "dot11.advertisedssid.wpa_mfp_supported": 0,
        "dot11.advertisedssid.dot11d_country": "",
        "dot11.advertisedssid.dot11d_list": [
        ],
        "dot11.advertisedssid.wps_state": 0,
        "dot11.advertisedssid.dot11r_mobility": 0,
        "dot11.advertisedssid.dot11r_mobility_domain_id": 0,
        "dot11.advertisedssid.dot11e_qbss": 0,
        "dot11.advertisedssid.dot11e_qbss_stations": 0,
        "dot11.advertisedssid.dot11e_channel_utilization_perc": 0.000000,
        "dot11.advertisedssid.ccx_txpower": 0,
        "dot11.advertisedssid.cisco_client_mfp": 0,
        "dot11.advertisedssid.ie_tag_list": [
          0.000000,
          1.000000,
          3.000000,
          5.000000,
          42.000000,
          50.000000,
          48.000000,
          45.000000,
          61.000000,
          127.000000,
          221.000000
        ]
      }
    }
```

Thanks for the help!

PS. This is from the new `kismet` database and the redesigned schema.

Here is the whole object:

```
   {
  "kismet.device.base.manuf": "Texas Instruments",
  "kismet.device.base.key": "4202770D00000000_AFB4F569D2380000",
  "kismet.device.base.macaddr": "38:D2:69:F5:B4:AF",
  "kismet.device.base.phyname": "IEEE802.11",
  "kismet.device.base.phyid": 0,
  "kismet.device.base.name": "LincolnFES-WiFi",
  "kismet.device.base.commonname": "LincolnFES-WiFi",
  "kismet.device.base.type": "Wi-Fi AP",
  "kismet.device.base.basic_type_set": 1,
  "kismet.device.base.crypt": "WPA2-PSK",
  "kismet.device.base.basic_crypt_set": 2,
  "kismet.device.base.first_time": 1559567379,
  "kismet.device.base.last_time": 1559567379,
  "kismet.device.base.mod_time": 1559567380,
  "kismet.device.base.packets.total": 3,
  "kismet.device.base.packets.rx": 0,
  "kismet.device.base.packets.tx": 0,
  "kismet.device.base.packets.llc": 3,
  "kismet.device.base.packets.error": 0,
  "kismet.device.base.packets.data": 0,
  "kismet.device.base.packets.crypt": 0,
  "kismet.device.base.packets.filtered": 0,
  "kismet.device.base.datasize": 0,
  "kismet.device.base.packets.rrd": {
    "kismet.common.rrd.last_time": 1559567383,
    "kismet.common.rrd.minute_vec": [
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      1,
      2,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0
    ],
    "kismet.common.rrd.blank_val": 0,
    "kismet.common.rrd.aggregator": "default",
    "kismet.common.rrd.hour_vec": [
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0
    ],
    "kismet.common.rrd.day_vec": [
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0
    ]
  },
  "kismet.device.base.signal": {
    "kismet.common.signal.type": "dbm",
    "kismet.common.signal.last_signal": -56,
    "kismet.common.signal.last_noise": 0,
    "kismet.common.signal.min_signal": -74,
    "kismet.common.signal.min_noise": 0,
    "kismet.common.signal.max_signal": -56,
    "kismet.common.signal.max_noise": 0,
    "kismet.common.signal.maxseenrate": 10,
    "kismet.common.signal.encodingset": 1,
    "kismet.common.signal.carrierset": 1,
    "kismet.common.signal.signal_rrd": {
      "kismet.common.rrd.last_time": 1559567383,
      "kismet.common.rrd.minute_vec": [
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0
      ],
      "kismet.common.rrd.blank_val": 0,
      "kismet.common.rrd.aggregator": "peak_signal"
    }
  },
  "kismet.device.base.freq_khz_map": {
    "2437000.000000": 1,
    "2442000.000000": 1,
    "5500000.000000": 1
  },
  "kismet.device.base.channel": "6",
  "kismet.device.base.frequency": 2442000,
  "kismet.device.base.num_alerts": 0,
  "kismet.device.base.tags": {

  },
  "kismet.device.base.seenby": {
    "-1970862229": {
      "kismet.common.seenby.uuid": "5FE308BD-0000-0000-0000-00C0CAA60413",
      "kismet.common.seenby.first_time": 1559567379,
      "kismet.common.seenby.last_time": 1559567379,
      "kismet.common.seenby.num_packets": 3,
      "kismet.common.seenby.freq_khz_map": {
        "2437000.000000": 1,
        "2442000.000000": 1,
        "5500000.000000": 1
      },
      "kismet.common.seenby.signal": {
        "kismet.common.signal.type": "dbm",
        "kismet.common.signal.last_signal": -56,
        "kismet.common.signal.last_noise": 0,
        "kismet.common.signal.min_signal": -74,
        "kismet.common.signal.min_noise": 0,
        "kismet.common.signal.max_signal": -56,
        "kismet.common.signal.max_noise": 0,
        "kismet.common.signal.maxseenrate": 10,
        "kismet.common.signal.encodingset": 1,
        "kismet.common.signal.carrierset": 1,
        "kismet.common.signal.signal_rrd": {
          "kismet.common.rrd.last_time": 1559567383,
          "kismet.common.rrd.minute_vec": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "kismet.common.rrd.blank_val": 0,
          "kismet.common.rrd.aggregator": "peak_signal"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "kismet.device.base.server_uuid": "A8F71A2C-85F8-11E9-BA41-4B49534D4554",
  "dot11.device": {
    "dot11.device.typeset": 257,
    "dot11.device.client_map": {

    },
    "dot11.device.num_client_aps": 0,
    "dot11.device.advertised_ssid_map": {
      "733545801": {
        "dot11.advertisedssid.ssid": "LincolnFES-WiFi",
        "dot11.advertisedssid.ssidlen": 15,
        "dot11.advertisedssid.beacon": 1,
        "dot11.advertisedssid.probe_response": 1,
        "dot11.advertisedssid.channel": "6",
        "dot11.advertisedssid.ht_mode": "HT20",
        "dot11.advertisedssid.ht_center_1": 0,
        "dot11.advertisedssid.ht_center_2": 0,
        "dot11.advertisedssid.first_time": 1559567379,
        "dot11.advertisedssid.last_time": 1559567379,
        "dot11.advertisedssid.beacon_info": "",
        "dot11.advertisedssid.cloaked": 0,
        "dot11.advertisedssid.crypt_set": 268436162,
        "dot11.advertisedssid.maxrate": 65,
        "dot11.advertisedssid.beaconrate": 10,
        "dot11.advertisedssid.beacons_sec": 2,
        "dot11.advertisedssid.ietag_checksum": 1220416683,
        "dot11.advertisedssid.wpa_mfp_required": 0,
        "dot11.advertisedssid.wpa_mfp_supported": 0,
        "dot11.advertisedssid.dot11d_country": "",
        "dot11.advertisedssid.dot11d_list": [

        ],
        "dot11.advertisedssid.wps_state": 0,
        "dot11.advertisedssid.dot11r_mobility": 0,
        "dot11.advertisedssid.dot11r_mobility_domain_id": 0,
        "dot11.advertisedssid.dot11e_qbss": 0,
        "dot11.advertisedssid.dot11e_qbss_stations": 0,
        "dot11.advertisedssid.dot11e_channel_utilization_perc": 0,
        "dot11.advertisedssid.ccx_txpower": 0,
        "dot11.advertisedssid.cisco_client_mfp": 0,
        "dot11.advertisedssid.ie_tag_list": [
          0,
          1,
          3,
          5,
          42,
          50,
          48,
          45,
          61,
          127,
          221
        ]
      }
    },
    "dot11.device.num_advertised_ssids": 1,
    "dot11.device.probed_ssid_map": {

    },
    "dot11.device.num_probed_ssids": 0,
    "dot11.device.associated_client_map": {

    },
    "dot11.device.num_associated_clients": 0,
    "dot11.device.client_disconnects": 0,
    "dot11.device.last_sequence": 0,
    "dot11.device.bss_timestamp": 0,
    "dot11.device.num_fragments": 0,
    "dot11.device.num_retries": 0,
    "dot11.device.datasize": 0,
    "dot11.device.datasize_retry": 0,
    "dot11.device.last_probed_ssid_csum": 0,
    "dot11.device.last_beaconed_ssid": "LincolnFES-WiFi",
    "dot11.device.last_beaconed_ssid_checksum": 733545801,
    "dot11.device.last_bssid": "38:D2:69:F5:B4:AF",
    "dot11.device.last_beacon_timestamp": 1559567379,
    "dot11.device.wps_m3_count": 0,
    "dot11.device.wps_m3_last": 0,
    "dot11.device.wpa_handshake_list": [

    ],
    "dot11.device.wpa_nonce_list": [

    ],
    "dot11.device.wpa_anonce_list": [

    ],
    "dot11.device.wpa_present_handshake": 0,
    "dot11.device.min_tx_power": 0,
    "dot11.device.max_tx_power": 0,
    "dot11.device.supported_channels": [

    ],
    "dot11.device.link_measurement_capable": 0,
    "dot11.device.neighbor_report_capable": 0,
    "dot11.device.extended_capabilities": [

    ],
    "dot11.device.beacon_fingerprint": 4212996422,
    "dot11.device.probe_fingerprint": 0,
    "dot11.device.response_fingerprint": 0
  }
}
```

Comment: Your sample isn't valid json...

Comment: Yes, this a subset of the larger object. Here is the whole object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to recursively walk through the fields of an entire object and its contents, you need [json_tree()](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#the_json_each_and_json_tree_table_valued_functions):

```
SELECT j.value
FROM devices AS d
JOIN json_tree(d.device) AS j
WHERE j.key = 'dot11.advertisedssid.ssid';
```

gives

```
value         
--------------
SampleFES-WiFi
```

when run on a table holding a fixed version of that sample object.

Comment: Thank you very much. That works (of course). It’s also simple!  And to think I wasted about two weeks of free time trying to figure this out!

Comment: Is it possible to select more than one field at a time with json_tree in this solution? Say I wanted the ssid and kismet.device.base.key?

Comment: @C0ntr07 use OR or IN?

Comment: Thank you. I tried that but my data is in one column because  (I think) I only have one select. But I don’t know how to fix that when using the json tree. Should I add a second item in the select statement?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old, but OP seemed (in comments) to want a more complete solution. I know I did when I first came across this answer. The accepted solution allows you to pull in ***one*** field from the JSON blob, but the common use case in OP's example is to pull multiple fields from that blob.  After some searching I found that the `json_extract()` function works very well for this once you realize that the `"dot11.device.advertised_ssid_map"` object is an array. Once you provide it with an index his normal query method works.

**Considerations:**

- OP's example is relating to the Kismet device field in the devices table, so my example will use a common query that I often need in the context of that table
- With Kismet the keys used in these JSON blobs are long and contain dots, so the syntax for specifying them in SQLite3 is a bit cumbersome for some nested values
- SQLite3's JSON1 extension does not seem to like some of the wildcarding syntax normally allowed in JSONPath specifications, so long explicit paths are required

So here is my solution:

```
SELECT devmac, strongest_signal, 
  json_extract(d.device, '$."dot11.device"."dot11.device.advertised_ssid_map"[0]."dot11.advertisedssid.ssid"') AS ssid,
  json_extract(d.device, '$."dot11.device"."dot11.device.advertised_ssid_map"[0]."dot11.advertisedssid.cloaked"') AS cloaked,
  json_extract(d.device, '$."kismet.device.base.signal"."kismet.common.signal.min_signal"') AS weakest_signal,
  json_extract(d.device, '$."kismet.device.base.channel"') AS channel,
  json_extract(d.device, '$."dot11.device"."dot11.device.num_associated_clients"') AS clientCnt,
  json_extract(d.device, '$."kismet.device.base.crypt"') AS crypt,
  json_extract(d.device, '$."kismet.device.base.manuf"') AS manuf
FROM devices AS d
WHERE type = 'Wi-Fi AP'
;
```